# jQuery/JavaScript regex return matched text from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to create a fairly complex system for my website. I want to be able to write some pseudo like code and then parse it to make it do something in my back-end.

My data is inside two $.each loops as this is an Object of data with multiple levels to it.

For instance, I want to take a string like this:

```
"<!this!> == <!PropertyStreetNumber!>"
```

Then how I would like for the above code to executed is this:

```
FormData[parentKey][this] == FormData[parentKey]["PropertyStreetNumber"]
```

Thanks for any help!

Here's some of my code, the code where this would need to go in (see commented area)
http://jsbin.com/liquvetapibu/1/

Comment: What is your backend language? Are you parsing this with C#, PHP, etc?

Comment: This is pure JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: did you wrote something?

Comment: Can't you use any other templating libraries that already exist?

Comment: Simple reg exp to parse out the parts. What did you try?

Comment: @epascarello For the nature of this site I need to use as little libraries as I can.

Comment: Do you have an actual working set of code?  What is parentKey? Where does it come from?  Is the string that you want to parse actually regular?  `this` gets transformed into an object, but `PropertyStreetNumber` gets turned into a String.  How do you tell the difference?

Comment: I added my code, it doesn't work in the JSbin as there are many other components to it, however it should give you a better sense of what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any restriction not to use regular expressions on JavaScript?

You could do something like this:

```
var myString = "<!this!> == <!PropertyStreetNumber!>";
var aux = /<!(.*?)!> == <!(.*?)!>/.exec(myString);
```

The value of `aux` will be an array with 3 elements:

1. The string that was tested.
2. The first element within `<! !>`
3. The second element within `<! !>`

Then it would depend on what the content on each one is: in your example `this` is an object, while you seem to use `PropertyStreetNumber` as a string (maybe a typo?). If you want to use it as an object, you will have to use `eval()` (e.g.: `eval(aux[1])`) while if you want to use it as a string, you can use it directly (e.g.: `aux[2]`).

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the first thing you would need to do is determine the type of statement you are working with. In this case, a comparison statement. So you need a regex statement to filter this into a "statement type".

Once you do that, you can figure out what the arguments are. So you create a regex to pull out the arguments on each side of the operator.

Next, the strings that represent action code items need to be parsed. The `this` argument is actually an object, whereas "PropertyStreetNumber" is a string. You've got to be able to determine which is which. Then you can filter that into a function that has been created specifically to handle those statements types.

If at all possible, I would try to avoid the use of `eval()`. You can get into trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try with

```
var beg = str.indexOf("== <!") + 5;
```

to find the index of the beggining and then slice counting the chars from beginning like

`str.slice(beg, -2);`

and from there build the rest.

couldnt that work?`